# Change display order of PictureBox controls

Tags: c#, image, stack

I am a student currently and I am quite new to C#, I am currently working on a school project to create a game but I am facing a `PictureBox` stacking problem. `PictureBox` that I initialize first are at the front, and all other `PictureBox` I initialize are behind it, it looks something like this,

[image: http://imgur.com/8m36YgC]

Is there anyway that I can bring the photo up? this is how my code looks like.

```
handCardString = new List<string>();
handCardString = h.displayHand();
handCards = new PictureBox[99];

int q = 0;
int loca1 = 439;

foreach (string s in handCardString)
{
    handCards[q] = new PictureBox();
    String r = String.Format("c:/Users/youhj/Desktop/CA1/Cards/{0}.jpg",s);
    Image ph = Image.FromFile(@r);
    handCards[q].Image = ph;
    pCardPhoto.Add(handCards[q]);
    pCardPhoto[q].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(loca1, 383);
    pCardPhoto[q].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 126);
    pCardPhoto[q].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pCardPhoto[q].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    this.Controls.Add(pCardPhoto[q]);
    loca1 += 20;
    q++;
}
```

Comment: @musefan okay, i am sorry, i will be careful next time. thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

WinForms controls generally don't stack and there is no true support for transparency. If you want custom rendering of images to support this use then author a custom `Control` with your own `OnPaint` routine.

Another option is to use WPF which is more flexible in this regard, though has a different programming model and a steeper learning curve.